# how to encode url with urllib without replacing ":" into "%3A"?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib2, urlencode

I need to pass some string as a paramters for a REST api.
I am using httplib2 to request the API and urllib to encode the parameters.

I have something like this with timestamp of format:

```
('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')/2019-07-08T13:20:23
```

and i am doing it like this below:

```
values={'identifier' : identifier,
        'timestamp': timestamp,
        'signature-version': signature_version,
        'signature-method':signature_method,
         'signature': signature}
```

now on doing urlencode it removes ":" into "%3A".

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
```

and it gives me back time as

```
timestamp=2019-07-08T13%3A20%3A23#
```

is there anything within the library that can ignore this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using urlencode, it would always turn ':' into '%3A' because that's the only way the url will parse it. It is the same as passing a space character as '%20'.
'%3A' character won't hamper the function of your code.

Comment: thanks for your reply. can you please propose any solution for that? thanks

Comment: use replace function

`data=.urllib.parse.urlencode(values).replace('%3A',':')`